# Fixed height elements with flexible width to fit the text contents inside

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I need to make each of my **floated** `<p>` elements take a fixed height of 200px, but also have a responsive width to fit all text contents inside.

Just be sure height is fixed 200px and if the content small and fitting just keep the current width 150px.

You can use any of those Languages for solution **(CSS, Javascript *(or jQuery)*, PHP)**

Current code

CSS

```
p{
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:17px
}

span{
    font-size:21px;
    color:red
}
```

HTML

```
<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur adipiscing elit. <b>Duis pharetra</b> quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit <span>amet aliquet ac, varius id eros.</span></p>

<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros. <b>Cras vitae orci in felis blandit elementum</b>. Mauris scelerisque mauris ante, <span>sed interdum tellus tincidunt id.</span> Cras ullamcorper vestibulum dolor quis pharetra. Phasellus quis dictum massa, <span>sit amet cursus lorem.</span></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipiscing elit.</b> Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros. Cras vitae orci in felis blandit elementum. Mauris scelerisque mauris ante, sed interdum tellus tincidunt id.</p>
```

Check and try the code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/

And this the output I want to reach

http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/4/

Is this possible?

Comment: Why you set a 400px height in the output if the p height should be fix and you want a "responsive width"?

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli unfortunately i did not focus :(, now i edit my question hoping for right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/2/)**

Set `min-height` instead of `height` for your `p` elements:

```
p {
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

---

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/5/)**

For **flexible** width, try this JS code:

```
$(function () {
    function checkHeight() {
        $('p').each(function () {
            var $p = $(this);
            var height = $p.height();

            if (height > 200) {                
                $p.css('width', '+=10');
                checkHeight();
            }
        });
    }

    checkHeight();
});
```

Comment: Fixed *height*, flexible *width*. But your example seems to be the solution

Comment: I'm sorry I added bad example for what i want to reach, this what I want http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/4/ for flexible width

Comment: OMG!, Thank You :), I lost hope for an answer because of my fault, Thank You so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `min-width:150px`? like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ym6nh/1/)

And again, you are talking about

> fixed height of 200px, but also have a responsive width to fit all
>   text contents inside.

why in your example you changed the height?

Comment: I'm sorry I added bad example for what i want to reach, this what I want http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/4/ for flexible width

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 height:200px;
```

to

```
 height:auto;
```

Let me know is this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-row and table-cell property` for this,

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Qet6p/3/